# Warlock Pact weapon on Sentient or Artifact Magic weapon

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, warlock, artifacts, intelligent-magic-items

I have read this part about Warlocks

> You can transform one magic weapon into your pact weapon by performing a special ritual while you hold the weapon. You perform the ritual over the course of I hour, which can be done during a short rest. *You can then dismiss the weapon, shunting it into an extradimensional space, and it appears whenever you create your pact weapon thereafter*. **You can't affect an artifact or a sentient weapon in this way**. The weapon ceases being your pact weapon if you die. if you perform the 1-hour ritual on a different weapon, or if you use a 1-hour ritual to break your bond to it. The weapon appears at your feet if it is in the extradimensional space when the bond breaks.

Does the restriction only apply to the extradimensional space feature? or does it mean you just can't fully make a sentient or artifact as your pact weapon?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### It means you can't make an artifact or sentient weapon a pact weapon

They are separate sentences, and are independent of each other.

I found a [Sage Advice column](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/06/29/clarify-blade-pact-cant-make-sentient-weapon-a-pact-weapon/) supporting this:

> @JeremyECrawford @mikemearls Clarify Blade Pact: can't make sentient weap pact weapon, or just can't dismiss it into extradimensional space?
>
> — Y. Michael Zhang (@YMichaelZhang) June 6, 2017

> Pact of the Blade. **You can't make a sentient weapon or an artifact your pact weapon.** #DnD https://t.co/DDNjLOYEK6
>
> — Jeremy Crawford (@JeremyECrawford) June 6, 2017

So that's that, it seems, but wait, there's more!

In this thread, Jeremy Crawford further goes on to explain that the limitation can be overridden by the DM:

> Why prevent it from happening then? Preventing it seems like an assumption that there will be those items in the game. We prevent it because those items have powers and story weight beyond regular magic items. **As always, a DM can override our design.**
>
> — Jeremy Crawford (@JeremyECrawford) June 6, 2017

Comment: I'd be surprised if they told the DM can't override that.