# Does the Hexblade Warlock's Hex Warrior feature apply to a magic weapon that is transformed into your Pact Weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, hexblade

The Hexblade Warlock's Hex Warrior feature states (emphasis mine):

> [...] If you later gain the Pact of the Blade feature, this benefit extends to every pact weapon you **conjure with that feature**, no matter the weapon's type.

Meanwhile, the [Pact of the Blade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#PactBoon-389) Warlock feature states:

> [...] You can transform one magic weapon into your pact weapon by performing a special ritual while you hold the weapon. You perform the ritual over the course of 1 hour, which can be done during a short rest. You can then dismiss the weapon, shunting it into an extradimensional space, and it appears whenever you create your pact weapon thereafter. [...]

Does a magic weapon that you have transformed into your pact weapon benefit from Hex Warrior?
Does it count as a weapon you have *conjured* using Pact of the Blade?
Does the answer change if you shunt the weapon away and then make it appear afterwards?

Comment: Related: confirmation that you can make a magical non-melee weapon your Pact Weapon: [Can I have a magic bow as my pact weapon without getting the Improved Pact Weapon Eldritch Invocation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/172746) (but doesn't mention Hex Warrior).  Also, more general coverage of the limitations and interactions of Hex Warrior and Pact of the Blade wrt. ranged and thrown-melee weapons: [Does the Hex Warrior feature allow a Hexblade warlock to create a ranged pact weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/191508)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

First of all, the weapon has been transformed into your pact weapon, so that checks out. But is it "conjured" when you make it appear?

Conjuration school of magic includes summoning spells, including spells like [*Instant Summons*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/instant-summons) and [*Secret Chest*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/secret-chest) , which kinda do similar things.

Also, the plain English meaning of "conjure" is

> to make something appear by magic, or as if by magic

(From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conjure?q=Conjure) )

And this is clearly what is happening here. There is no clear definition of "conjuring" in 5th edition which would contradict this.

So, it would be extremely strange for a DM to rule that making your magic pact weapon appear would not count as conjuring a pact weapon with the Pact of the Blade feature.

Comment: Note that sentient or artifact weapons can't be dismissed / summoned, even if you can bond one as your Pact Weapon.  (The *You can't affect an artifact or a sentient weapon in this way.* isn't clear whether it applies to bonding it as a pact weapon at all, or just to the dismiss/summon sentence immediately before it.)

Comment: Another question has that answer. [Link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107784/warlock-pact-weapon-on-sentient-or-artifact-magic-weapon?rq=1)